# The [kaleidoscope] tag has multiple uses

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

I think we should clean up the [kaleidoscope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kaleidoscope) tag. It has a few useless uses (*I'll be updating these as I see them*):

- pictures and images of kaleidoscopes
- working with llvm.org's Kaleidoscope example
- stuff about the Amizograph app
- a git difftool

As is evident, none are really related in any way; the tag is used if the content has anything to do with any kind of kaleidoscope.

**Note:** This tag has been cleared up. Thanks to [Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339780/7292857) for fixing the usage.

Comment: As usual with these "burninate" requests, you are a bit confused. Kaleidoscope is *not* "a git extension", it is a popular diff program for the Mac. It has absolutely nothing to do with git, except for in that particular case, they're using it as the git difftool. Since Kaleidoscope (like all diff programs) is a tool commonly used by programmers, it is perfectly on-topic here, and the tag is perfectly reasonable. Questions involving pictures and images of kaleidoscopes should obviously *not* have that tag, and should probably be closed. As far as I can tell, that is the only problematic case.

Comment: Meta doesn't suck, you just don't know how it works. You made a proposal, which people disagreed with, so they downvoted it. Reputation doesn't exist here, so there is really nothing to complain about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) is indeed a diff tool  for Mac (and it's pretty decent if I do say so myself), we should converge on the uses of this tag to be specific about this tool instead.

This means:

- <s>Retag and review all questions about kaleidoscope pictures</s> (Done)
- <s>Since [Amaizograph](http://www.amaziograph.com/) is its own kind of app, questions *specifically* pertaining to it should be closed</s> (Done; only one was in the tag set and it was still a valid programming question)
- <s>If there are kaleidoscope-specific questions pertaining to LLVM, then if they're worth saving, they should be prefixed (e.g. [llvm-kaleidoscope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llvm-kaleidoscope)) - not saying that should be the *final* tag, but it's a suggestion.</s> (Done; for the time being, I left it tagged with LLVM since it pertains specifically to LLVM)

The first two bullet points can be worked on immediately since there's only 18 questions here.  <s>The third one, I'd like more discussion on; I may even open up a different question for it later if I find any LLVM-specific kaleidoscope questions.</s>  After reading more of the LLVM example, it really is just a toy language that they call "kaleidoscope".  This in my mind makes it eligible to just be tagged under LLVM instead.  Same discussion principle applies though.